# Online flexible survey constructor (maybe kind of decision making software)

Tags: web-apps, web-services, cloud-service, survey, saas

I need a software recommendation for direct democracy :)

I'm searching for a solution for a non-profit organization. When preparing grant requests or preparing year development program, each member votes for most important tasks according to his opinion.

E.g. We have the opportunity to buy Thing A, Thing B and Thing C. I need a form interface which allow user to drag-n-drop items to sort them in desirable order. And as alternative option, help to make a decision by constructing list of questions with two answers, e.g. "What is important, Thing A or Thing B", "Thing A or Thing C" and "Thing B or Thing C". 
And of course, there must me clear interface which shows results.

Preferably software must be SaaS, free and simple.

Already checked Surveymonkey, Google Forms and TypeForm but seems like there is no such possibility in them.

Comment: UPD: At this moment, I think most close (though it's not so simple) solution is 1000minds.com which uses PAPRIKA method (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision-making_software)

Answer (score 1):

[LimeSurvey](https://www.limesurvey.org/en/) has such a feature. The question type is called "Ranking". You can define a list of items

[image: LimeSurvey question definition]

and the user can then define the ranking by drag'n'drop:

[image: LimeSurvey ordering items]

LimeSurvey is available [as a service](https://www.limesurvey.org/en/services) or you can [download and install](https://www.limesurvey.org/en/#download) your own copy.

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I work for PollUnit

With our poll maker PollUnit (a SAAS platform I'm working for) it is now possible to rank options by drag and drop. An overall rating is then calculated based on all participants answers.

You can read more here in our blogpost: https://pollunit.com/en/posts/172/ranking-questions-in-online-surveys

Cheers
Philipp[image: Illustration for ranked voting]